# Bold text using the dnaseq package

Tags: formatting

I need to print very long DNA sequences, and for this I use the dnaseq package.
Is there any way to format parts of a DNA sequence as bold?
The package allows the usage of ’{} to change the color of the
bases background, but I could not find a way to change the formatting. using \textbf{} does not work.

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dnaseq}

\begin{document}

% in this example I would like TAATACGACTCACTATAGGG to be bold and without
% background, rather than having a SpringGreen background

\DNA! '{SpringGreen} TAATACGACTCACTATAGGG '{white} AACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAA
CGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGT
CATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATG !

\end{document}
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of problems that have to be overcome.  First, the default Computer Modern font does not support bold `\ttfamily`, so you need a different font.  Then, you have the situation where the fixed-width of the medium-series font is different than the fixed width of the bold-series (this is the case at least in `lmodern`), so your alignments would get screwed up.

Then, you have to find out where the color is set by the package, which I located to be the `\@DNA` macro.  Finally, you have to adjust the macro to suit.  What I did was employ a new macro `\boxwidth` to specify the width of the box into which each character is set, which will overcome the issue of bold fonts having different width than medium-series fonts.  I also adjusted the meaning of the `'{...}` specifier to do the things you want.

In the MWE, I demonstrate bold, cyan colorbox, italic, red, and `\scriptsize\rmfamily`.

```
\documentclass[addpoints, a4paper, 12pt]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dnaseq}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\makeatletter
\def\@DNA#1{%
%% insert a space after \DNAblock bases
   \ifnum\count@=\DNAblock\count@=0\ %
   \advance\@tempcnta by 1\fi
   \def\@DNA@cmp{#1}%
%% check for end of sequence or color shift
   \ifx\@DNA@cmp\@DNA@end
     \let\next\egroup
   \else
     \ifx\@DNA@cmp\@DNA@color
       \let\next\@DNA@setcolor
     \else
       \advance\count@ by 1
       \advance\@tempcntb by 1
%% line break after calculated number of blocks
       \ifnum\@tempcnta=\blocks \\
         \hskip\z@\phantom{\DNAreserve}\llap {\the\@tempcntb}\ %
         \@tempcnta=0
       \fi
       \makebox[\boxwidth]{\struty\@DNA@thecolor{#1}}%
       \penalty0\let\next\@DNA
     \fi
   \fi
   \next
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\boxwidth{1.1ex}
\begin{document}
\DNA! 
  '{\textbf} TAATACGACTCACTATAGGG 
  '{\colorbox{cyan}} AACGCTAGTC
  '{} ATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTA GTCATGCATC 
  '{\textit} GTATGTAACG 
  '{\textcolor{red}} CTAGTCATGC 
  '{\scriptsize\rmfamily} ATCGTATGTA 
  '{} ACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGT
     CATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACG
     CTAGTCATGCATCGTATGTAACGCTAGTCATG 
!
\end{document}
```

[image]